# How do I change a class in HTML using PHP?

Tags: php, html, class

I have the code below in all of my pages, except for each page, the class is on that specific page.

```
<li><a href="../index.html">Homescreen</a></li>
<li><a href="socialstuff.html">Social Stuff</a></li>
<li><a href="sops.html">SOP's</a></li>
<li><a href="login.php">FTO Documents</a></li>
<li><a class="selected" href="changelog.html">Changelog</a></li>
```

I am working on throwing these inside of an include folder, that way each page I create does not have to have this line of code in each page. My only question is, how do I detect what page I'm on, and then automatically remove the old class slected and add the new one to the current page?

Comment: How did you go with this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Taking the details from BayssMekanique's answer but making a more systematic response...   Iterating through your links would help.  I would also create a function `renderLinkList()` or similar, and return the string. Hope this helps.

```php
<?php 
   $links = '';

$links = array(
    'Homescreen'   => '../index.html',
    'Social Stuff' => 'socialstuff.html',
    'SOP\'s'        => 'sops.html',
    'FTO Docs'     => 'login.php',
    'Change Log'   => 'changelog.html'
);

for each ($links as $title => $href) { 
    $selected = '';
    if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']) == $href) {
        $selected = 'class="selected"';
    }
    $linkString  = '<li>';
    $linkString .= '<a href="'.$href.'" '.$selected.' >';
    $linkString .= $title.'</a></li>';
    $links .= $linkString;
}

//if you made a function you would now return links
print $links;
```

Comment: You should clear the `$selected` variable after appending it to the `$links` variable.
Else it'd apply the same class to all subsequent links.

Answer (score 1):

That largely depends on how you are handling routing.  Assuming you are using just file name routing, then you can use a URI check.

```
<li><a href="socialstuff.html" class="<?php if($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']) == 'socialstuff.html'){ echo 'selected'; } ?>">Social Stuff</a></li>
```

You would then do this for each line in your `<ul>` element.

Also, in the `if($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']) == 'socialstuff.html')` line, the `'socialstuff.html'` needs to be the exact URI that the address bar reads when you are on that page.  So if `socialstuff.html` resides in a folder called `misc`, and the URI for that page would probably be `misc/socialstuff.html`.

Comment: So how do I change said class to "selected"

Comment: I just changed it.  You would put the class you want applied inside the echo argument.

Answer (score 1):

One way that I tackle this is with a helper function.

```
function currentPage($page){

    if (basename($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']) == $page) {
        echo 'selected';
    }

}
```

```
        <li><a class="<?php currentPage('changelog.html') ?>" href="changelog.html">Changelog</a></li>
```

You will have to add this function to every `li` that you want to check if its that page

I havent tested the code, but you will get a general idea of how to handle this type of thing. Hope that helps.

Comment: This works! What I did was put this function inside my sidebar file. Works wonderful!